# How to get key of the biggest element in 2d array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Example array

```
$array[0][0] = 5323;
$array[0][1] = 5346;
$array[0][2] = 5424;
$array[1][0] = 6000;
$array[1][1] = 5412;
$array[1][2] = 5543;
$array[2][0] = 5651;
$array[2][1] = 7000;
$array[2][2] = 5254;
```

So biggest element in this array has value 7000;
**How to get his keys X and Y?** (as in $array[X][Y], so in this case that would be x = 2 and y = 1);

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through the array and save the x y when you get a new maximum value.

I start max with the minimum number possible and from there it loops the array and updates the variables if the value is larger than the previous max.

```
$max = PHP_INT_MIN;

foreach($array as $key => $subarray){
    foreach($subarray as $subkey => $value){
        if($value > $max){
            $x = $key;
            $y = $subkey;
            $max = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/5hHXP

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better/faster way than that one which is O(n^2) time complexity? Any way to do it in O(nlog(n))?

Comment: This method loops through all values once. There is no way you can make anything faster than that. I'm not sure I understand why this would be n^2. Are you sure you understand the code?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to make a string of your current array, and then create 
an array of all values in the string and fetch max value by using PHP's native function max on the array:

```
$na = '';
foreach($array as $arr) {
    $na .= implode(',',$arr) . ',';
}
$max_value = max(explode(',',$na));

foreach($array as $x=>$arr) {
    $y = array_search($max_value, $arr);    
    if ($y !== false) break;
}
```

Then you would have your values in $x, $y and $max_value

Comment: Interesting approach, but I think breaking it in string then converting back to array and then searching the new array is too much of a time wasted. There must be some way of searching array as it is. Either by using max() properly so it gives correct result with 2d array or if that is not possible then using a different function

Comment: @leyanes212 - max() would only work on one dimensional arrays. Another approach would be the one Andreas supplied :-) The benefit of doing this approach is that it could break out of the loop when the key is found. The drawback is maybe that there would be a long string ($na) that might not be easy to take care of if it is a very large array.

Comment: ***The benefit of doing this approach is that it could break out of the loop when the key is found.*** But that is the third time the value is processed. First you make a string of it, then an array and only at the third time can you "break" the loop.

Comment: @Andreas - That's completely true! I would say it depends on the size of array. Matybe it would benefit, maybe not. I was just looking for an alternative solution .-) Would be  cool to see some comparision in terms of processing time and sizes of array  :-)

Comment: There is now way on this planet as long as the Earth is moving around the sun that there is a benefit of processing the same values up to three times. Feel free to create such an example yourself.

Comment: haha maybe not :-) No I don't have the time for doing such a comparison.